# v-for loop is not working for array items

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a `v-for` loop that is supposed to loop an array of images url to assign them to the `src` attribute of a swiper instance. I'm facing the issue that the data are printed out as a single string separated by commas and the `<img>` tag will not be created for each image url in the array. Is there a solution? The problem occurs inside a vue component.

```
DOM Markup

<!-- swiper slider / this is part of a component -->
    <div class="row m-0" v-for="page in pageData">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-5 mt-5 mb-5" v-if="page.embedded.gallery_images">
        <div class="swiper-container page-carousel">
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <img v-for="img in feedImg" class="swiper-slide" :src="img" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
// Vue component

Vue.component('theme-page',{
  template: '#page-tpl',
  data(){
    return{
      pageData: [],
      feedImg: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route( to, from ){
      //console.log('c instance:'+ to, from);
      this.getPage();
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    this.getPage();
    this.initSwiper();
  },
  methods: {
    getPage: function(){
      console.log(this.$route.params.slug);
      axios.get(theme.pages_rest_url+'?slug='+ this.$route.params.slug)
        .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        response.data.forEach( (item, i) => {
          this.pageData = [item];
          this.feedImg = [item.embedded.gallery_images];
        });
        console.log(this.feedImg);
      });
    },
    initSwiper: function(){
      const feedSwiper = new Swiper('.page-carousel', {  
        slidesPerView: 4,
        //spaceBetween: 80,
        slidesPerGroup: 4,
        virtual: {
          cache: true,
          slides: this.feedImg,
          renderExternal: function(feedImg){
            this.feedImg = feedImg;
          }
        },
        //loop: true,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 5000
         },
        //loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
      });            
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: check with this where you are looping the img. <div class="swiper-wrapper" v-for="(img,idx) in feedImg" :key="idx">
            <img  class="swiper-slide" :src="img" />
          </div>

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean with check??

Comment: @Dcoder I've tested your suggested code, but no loop occurs and all the urls are printed as a single string list comma separated.

Comment: can u plz tell how data are present in feedimg?

Comment: can you provide us a sample data of how your `feedImg` array looks like

Comment: At first 

response.data.forEach( (item, i) => {
          this.pageData = [item];
          this.feedImg = [item.embedded.gallery_images];
        });

in this piece of code in each iteration you overwrite a previous value of this.pageData and this.feedImg and it leads to this.pageData and this.feedImg both store the last values from the response.data array

Comment: I have found a solution, I just used another `forEach` loop for the `feedImg` data, this because the initial provided array will become a string and not a loopable array. with the `forEach` loop instead, the data will be passed to the variable as an array and I'm able to loop them using `v-for="img in feedImg"` !